# My code outputs incorrectly

Tags: java, syntax-error, invalid-characters

I am trying to make a program that calculates the area of a triangle given the values for all three sides. When I run my program with my runner file my area comes out to " 0.0"

Here is the classes full code (also I know I did the same code for setSides and triangle but my instructor gave us this shell and I didn't know what to put in there)

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.lang.Math.*;

public class Triangle
{
 private int sideA;
 private int sideB;
 private int sideC;
 private double theArea; 
 private double s; 
 private double perimeter; 

 public Triangle()
 {
     sideA = 1;
     sideB = 1;
     sideC = 1;
 }

 public Triangle(int a, int b, int c)
 {
   sideA = (int) a;
   sideB = (int) b;
   sideC = (int) c;   
 }


 public void setSides(int a, int b, int c)
 {
   sideA = (int) a;
   sideB = (int) b;
   sideC = (int) c;
 }

 private double calcPerimeter()
 {
  double perimeter = sideA + sideB + sideC;
        return perimeter;
 }



private double calcArea()
 {
  double s = calcPerimeter() / 2;
  double theArea = (Math.sqrt(s * (s - sideA) * (s - sideB) * (s - sideC))); 
  return theArea;
 }

 public void print()
 {
    System.out.println("Area == " + theArea); 
 }
}
```

Comment: @Daniel Stephens98: what is **permiter** ??

Comment: @Daniel Stephens98: and also you are not insitiating **S** variable in constructor and also using **S** locally and class memeber too ..

Comment: Also, your minus signs appear to be em-dashes

Answer (score 2):

I did an system out on your statement. What you are using is not an subtract operator. Please fix that. It will work. Also define the `permiter`.

```
System.out.println((int)'–');
```

output:
8211

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you copied some of your source code from a document that isn't a simple text document?

If so, then your problem is that your minus signs are not the proper character. Try re-typing them in a text editor.

ED: Also, a minus sign should be surrounded by spaces. When I first looked at this, it threw me.

In your revised code, you can be square rooting a negative number, which would through you in a really bad state.

Comment: This was exactly what I was about to ask. It appears there is some wonky formatting going on here. +1 for proper formatting tips =)

Comment: @DanielStephens98 You don't define perimeter. instead of what you have put 'double s = calcPerimeter()/2;'

Comment: @TheThom when I instantiate " private double perimeter; " it fixes the error but now when I go ahead and run the program with my runner my area just come out to " 0.0 "

Comment: @DanielStephens98 Did you attempt the fix I posted before your comment?

Comment: @TheThom I downloaded it and used it but still my output is coming out to "0.0'

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
private double perimeter;
```

And change:

```
 private double calcArea()
 {
  double s = perimeter / 2;
  double theArea = (Math.sqrt(s * (s - sideA) * (s - sideB) * (s - sideC))); 
  return theArea;
 }
```

To:

```
 private double calcArea()
 {
  double s = calcPerimeter() / 2;
  double theArea = (Math.sqrt(s * (s - sideA) * (s - sideB) * (s - sideC))); 
  return theArea;
 }
```

Here is what is happening. You declare a private double called perimeter. Later in the code you once again declare a double called perimeter. When you do this, things get really confusing! Make sure you only declare variables with the same name ONCE, and reference them thereafter.

Comment: I went ahead and changed the code, but my output is still coming out to "0.0"

Comment: Change 2 to 2.0? You are working with both int and double types.